# ros_controller not making -indigo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-controllers, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to make my own costume robot in gazebo. I have been following this tutorials
http://www.generationrobots.com/en/content/75-gazebo-and-ros
http://www.romin.upm.es/wiki/index.php?title=ROS%3ATutorials/Simulate_Your_Robot_in_Gazebo

But when I try to run

```
catkin_make
```

I get the following error

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
any of the following names:

```
ros_controlConfig.cmake
ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ros_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  omni_shot/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

This is my CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  controller_manager 
  ros_control
  ros_controllers
  
)
```

Do I need to include ros_controller and ros_controllers? When I remove them I get thses errors,

```
[ERROR] [1451315533.235070013, 0.140000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'front_right_wheel_joint'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235176421, 0.140000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'front_right_wheel_joint_trans'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235239698, 0.140000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'front_left_wheel_joint'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235290363, 0.140000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'front_left_wheel_joint_trans'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235343496, 0.140000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'back_right_wheel_joint'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235391198, 0.140000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'back_right_wheel_joint_trans'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235439370, 0.140000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'back_left_wheel_joint'.
[ERROR] [1451315533.235487324, 0.140000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'back_left_wheel_joint_trans'
```

I have been stuck on this for over a day, can anyone please help me? I am very confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223186/ros_controller-not-making--indigo/) by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2015-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake is telling you that it can't find the `ros_control` package.

You should try installing it:

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control
```

Or on other operating systems, checkout the ros_control package from github: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control into your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1